# Not able to iterate array using Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following is my script function which is written in Angular.js

```
 $scope.newuser = function(){
     this.users.push([
        {
            firstname:$scope.firstname,
            lastname:$scope.lastname
        }
     ]);
     console.log($scope.users);        
 }
```

Now, I'm not able to iterate the array. Kindly help

Thank you

Comment: We need more info. How you try it, errors, etc.

Comment: function ctrl($scope){

    $scope.firstname = 'Nizam'; // Set First Name on Page Load.
    $scope.lastname = 'Ali'; // Set Last Name on Page Load.
    $scope.users = [];

    /**
     * Adding a new user.
    */
    $scope.newuser = function(){
        this.users.push(
            {
                firstname:$scope.firstname,
                lastname:$scope.lastname
            }
        );
        console.log($scope.users[0]['lastname']);        
    }


}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, most likely, is your use of `this`. In your code `this` would refer to your `newUser` function and therefore the users array does no exist in that context.

Based on your console.log statement, I think this should solve the problem.

```
$scope.newuser = function(){
     $scope.users.push([
        {
            firstname:$scope.firstname,
            lastname:$scope.lastname
        }
     ]);
     console.log($scope.users);        
 }
```